# How to remove ceramic faucet cartridge -single handle, unknown brand

Tags: faucet, replacement, cartridge

The challenge is figuring out what the metal piece is that is holding the cartridge in place, and how to remove that piece. It doesn't seem to turn or pull out straight using pliers to yank on two of the metal tabs.

[image: cartridge and cover]

Answer (score 1):

Turn the ring with the 4 square castles or "bumps' counter clockwise.

when it is removed the cartridge will come out.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to turn it by holding onto two of the bumps /tabs with pliers but it wouldn't budge.

Comment: Did you try a good penetrating fluid, @Katharina? Something like PB Blaster™ or Kroil™ - they're very good at breaking through rust & corrosion to free up bound nuts & bolts.

Answer (score 0):

Bend the 4 tongues inwards.

That will allow you to pull up the outer ring.

That one is holding the catrige